# Updating internal python class parameters with external functions

Tags: python, mutable

I have an external function `my_update_function` which is *not* part of my class `my_class` (currently for design reasons). Now, I would like to update the internal parameters of `my_class` i.e. `self.x` and `self.y` using the external function `my_update_function`.

Please see this MWE, which describes my questions:

```
def my_update_function(arg1,args2):
    """
    Updates arg1 and arg2.
    """
    return arg1*arg1,arg2*arg2

class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2
        self.y = 3
    def simulate(self):
        my_update_function(self.x,self.y)
```

However, I am wondering if there is some way (either by class re-design or otherwise) that I can update `self.x` and `self.y` *without* having to save the output of the function `my_update_function` as parameter values (and without having to include `my_update_function` as part of my class `my_class`) i.e I would rather not write this:

```
def simulate(self):
    self.x, self.y = my_update_function(self.x,self.y)
```

but would want it to be like this:

```
def simulate(self):
    my_update_function(self.x,self.y)
```

so that `my_update_function` communicates the updated parameter values to the class without having to explicitly store them as outputs.

Please let me know if it is not clear what I mean, and I shall update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def my_update_function(obj):
    obj.x, obj.y = obj.x * obj.x, obj.y * obj.y
```

then in your class:

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2
        self.y = 3
    def simulate(self):
        my_update_function(self)
```

Comment: Oh ok cool! Do you mind explaining how this works? Sorry have not seen this before.

Comment: @Astrid: it works by passing the object reference to the `my_update_function`, so the function can read and write the `x` and `y` attributes directly, without using arguments or return values.

Comment: @Astrid: depends on the context. Instead of returning the modified values, here you require that the passed object `obj` has two attributes:  `x` and `y`. Since python is dynamically typed, works with any object that has `x` and `y` attributes, and not just with objects of the class `my_class`. However that might be a bit less reusable than your initial approach using `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Since python does not have pointers, a common trick is to use lists, which are passed by reference, and hence their contents is *mutable*:

```
>>> def my_update_function(l):
...     l[0], l[1] = l[0] * l[0], l[1] * l[1]
...
>>> l = [2, 3]
>>> my_update_function(l)
>>> l
[4, 9]
```

I'm adding this as a second answer to not create confusion.

Using an object instead of a list works the same way (both are passed by reference), and you already have an object at hand, so you better off using the `my_class` object.

Comment: Ah that is great, did not know that. Is either preferred, compared to your other answer?

Comment: Both approaches are similar. The alternative approach is the one you started with, using `return`, which can be a bit more reusable, but requires you to explicitly assign the return values. It's up to your preference.